# Cómo incrementar últimos dígitos en una consulta

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta consulta,

```sql
SELECT CONCAT("T00", IFNULL(MAX(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(codtercero, 3, LENGTH (codtercero))),0)+1) as Nuevo FROM terceros WHERE idtipo=4
```

La cual funciona perfecto para ir agregando un código 
ejemplo
T001, 
T002, 
T003, pero una vez llego a T010, no sigue incrementando. 
Me repite. 
T0010, T0010 etc.

Agradezco algúna ayuda de porque ocurre esto.

[image: Consulta]

[image: Existe]

Comment: Pon un pequeño dataset de los valores de `codtercero` y también del resultado que te arroja.

Comment: Gracias por responder amigo. Cómo haría eso?

Comment: Copiando y pegando en la pregunta parte del resultado de un `SELECT` en ambos casos.

Comment: Listo amigo. Soy nuevo en Stackoverflow.

Comment: La consulta debería arrojarme T0011, porque el último es T0010. El funciona perfecto, pero cuando llega a T0010 deja de incrementar.

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo intentas con `LPAD`, haciéndola actuar exclusivamente sobre la columna `codtercero`. Por ejemplo, si haces algo como esto: `SELECT LPAD(codtercero,3,'0') AS cod FROM ...`  tendrás valores como `001, 002, 003... 009, 010, 011` y luego le puedes concatenar con `T`. No te escribo una respuesta porque me pierdo entre todo el lío del `DISTINCT`, del `MAX` del `SUBSTRING` y todo lo demás que tienes ahí sin llegar a entender cuál es la finalidad de todo eso. Revisa [la doc de `LPAD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad), creo que te ayudará.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te cuento que hace un tiempo cree un sistema en el cual tenia que crear un numero serial compuesto de letras y números y esto sucede por que el campo es varchar y cuando se trata de obtener el MAX() este lo trata como texto no como numero, para tal efecto puedes usar,

```
SELECT
MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(OrderNo,5,LEN(OrderNo)-4) AS INT))
FROM OrderSummary
WHERE OrderNo LIKE 'Ord-%'
```

como se indica en este ejemplo: [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547224/select-max-value-from-a-string-column-in-sql)

Para el caso en que tu sistema sea multiusuario usar un select para saber cual sera el siguiente valor, podría generar un error al estar 2 o mas usuarios ingresando el nuevo valor podrían obtener 3 usuarios el valor T0010, y seguido los 3 o mas usuarios ingresarían el valor T0011, por ende tendrías 3 registros con ese ordinal, para resolver esto lo que yo realice fue un Trigger que se gatilla al realizar una inserción en la base de datos de esta manera no tienes ese problema ya que esta acción es única y se realiza en dicha tabla solo una vez

```
BEFORE INSERT ON `base`.`tabla`
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de como debería quedar para tu caso.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`masterbase`@`localhost` TRIGGER `base`.`nombredeltrigger`
BEFORE INSERT ON `base`.`tabla`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  DECLARE maximoT00 INT;

 SET maximoT00 = (SELECT SUBSTRING(codtercero,4) FROM tabla WHERE idtipo=4 ORDER BY (idtercero) DESC  limit 1); 

   IF (maximoT00 IS NULL) THEN
        SET maximoT00 = 1;
  END IF;

 SET NEW.codtercero = CONCAT("T00", maximoT00 + 1 );

END
```

Comment: Amigo gracias. Al final me sirvió el CAST, al final quedó así. 
SELECT
CONCAT("T00", IFNULL(MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(codtercero,2,LENGTH(codtercero)) AS INT)),0)+1) as Nuevo 
FROM terceros 
WHERE idtipo=4

Comment: Voy a revisar lo del trigger.